# Can I stick with server_name directive from nginx or do I still need to set DNS in linux?

Tags: linux, nginx, dns

I am learning nginx and I have this doubt. Do I need to setup a dns in linux (/etc/resolv.conf) or can I just stay with what nginx uses inside its directive server_name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set nginx to listen to ANY domain pointed to that web server with:

```
listen       80  default_server;
```

or you can be specific via `server_name`. Check [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Setting DNS on the webserver itself does not help much..

Adding the entry in your visitor's PC `hosts` file can override a domain name's  A record pointer to the one specified by you.